# Odd truncation when converting list comprehensions to genexprs

Tags: python-3.x, generator

I've just written some code that uses a list comprehension at the front to build a list of positions that it needs to do things to.

```
tilewidth=tileheight=64
xs=[x*tilewidth for x in range(0,fillwidth//tilewidth)]
ys=[y*tileheight for y in range(0,fillheight//tileheight)]
positions=[(x,y) for x in xs for y in ys]
```

This gives

```
[(0, 0), (0, 64), (0, 128), ... (64, 0), (64, 64), (64, 128), ... (1216, 1152), (1216, 1216)]
```

which is exactly what I want.

However, when I try converting my list comprehensions to generators, simply by swapping the brackets for parentheses, I only get the (0,0) to (0, 1216) range. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generator can be iterated over only once. When you have nested iterators, the inner iterator will be iterated over only once, hence the foreshortened result.

---

```
[(x,y) for x in xs for y in ys]
```

is equivalent to

```
for x in xs:
    for y in ys:               
        result.append((x,y))
```

Above, if `ys` is a generator, `ys` can only be iterated over once. So the first time through the outer loop, for the first value of `x`, `ys` yields items. On subsequent iterations of `xs`, `ys` is *already consumed*, so no more items are appended to `result`.